# Are off-stage DisplayObjects in Flash still slowing down my game?

Tags: performance, flash, actionscript-3, rendering

How does Flash deal with elements that are off-stage?

Obviously Flash doesn't actually render them (because they don't appear anywhere on-screen), but is the process of rendering them still existent, slowing down my game as much as it would if the elements were on-screen?

Or does Flash intelligently ignore elements who don't fall into a renderable area?

Should I manually manage removing objects off the `DisplayList` and adding them back on as the exit and enter the stage, or is this going to be irrelevant?

Comment: You could write a simple test. Though they are not rendered they are still in the hierarchy and might be doing some nasty things like animating, executing scripts and dispatching tons of events.

Comment: i think the actual drawing of the objects eats most of the performance - so when they're off-stage that shouldn't be a problem. but as valentin said, when they're still "executing scripts and/or dispatching tons of events" they're definitely slowing down the whole game. if they won't reappear on stage, destroy them - if they will, try and "pause" them until they reappear...

Comment: I agree that you should write some tests, get a whole bunch of objects and animate them across and off the screen, using the Flash Builder profiler you should be able to locate any bottle necks.

I would test with just seeing them go off screen, and also test removeChild() and visible after going off screen, do not use alpha 0 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are slowing down your game.

In one of my early experiments I've developed a sidescroller game with many NPCs scattered around the map, not all visible in the same screen. I still had to calculate stuff but they weren't on the screen. The performance was significantly better when I handled their removal off the display list when irrelevant (by simply checking their X in relation to the 'camera'). Again, I'm not talking about additional code and events that may be attached to them, just plain graphical children of a movieclip.

The best practice though, in my experience, is drawing the objects in bitmaps. Of course if you're too deep into your game already this may be irrelevant, but if you have the time to invest, this is one of the best ways to get the most out of AS3 regarding 2D games. I found some of the greatest tutorials regarding bitmaps and AS3 in 8bitrocket 
http://www.8bitrocket.com/books/the-essential-guide-to-flash-games/ I can elaborate on the subject if you want, but I think I'm going off topic here.

Comment: Good background - and good advice about bitmaps; this is something I have been doing for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Even if some display objects are out of the stage area, they are still executed. If they have any animation playing in them, that might slow down the performance.

The question arises, why do we need to keep unused items outside the stage area? if you need to 'cache' the movieClips for faster loading , then load them in a keyframe where the control will never go. for eg. load the display objects which you want to show in frame 1, then put a stop() in the actions panel of the frame, make it a key frame, and in frame 2 load the unused animations. since there is a stop() in frame 1, the control never goes in frame 2, but the display objects are cached.

Or, if you have codes in the unsused displayobjects, and thus need to load them along with the main game components, then, try putting stop() in the frames of the unused display objects so that they don't animate.